# inhomogeneous confluent hypergeometrtic differential equation

Tags: differential

I'm looking for the particular solution of an nonhomogeneous second order differential equation. The inhomogeneous term is a function of the form: 1u1u. I've tried to find the particular solution by the "varying constant technique". That is, if the solution of the homogeneous equation is C 1F1(a,b,u)C 1F1(a,b,u), I look for a particular solution of the form C~(x) 1F1(a,b,u)C~(x) 1F1(a,b,u). The problem is that this method is not giving me a good result.

Is there any way of trying to get the particular solution by hand (taking into account that the inhomogeneous term is of the form 1/u)?

Thanks!

Comment: I cannot see the ODE you are trying to solve. Some of your symbols are mysterious : what is 1u1u ?

Comment: The equation is
xy"(x)+(1-x)y'(x)+by(x)=k/x